# ipython notebook: how to save output in the system?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am working on ipython notebook to apply tf-idf and knn model. I want to save the output of below command in excel: knn_model.query(Var, k = 20) . I can see it in the notebook but dont know how to save this output in my system. Please help.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest answer: Copy paste the result to a file, which you could use as input to where you want to use the result?! Using any text-editor where you opened a new file to copy into.

More complicated answer: you forget to tell where the out put has to go ... Python has lots of possibilities to export Python created output to.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am getting only 10 rows in the ipython notebook output. But I want to see the entire set of rows for which I need to extract this table in excel file. Can you help me with this?